Mysql miss count of string, bug?
Here my mysql query to count the repeated item,
SELECT
  count(item),
  item,
  name,
  area
FROM jmr
WHERE starttime LIKE '2024-05-03%' and area='DC'
group by item, name;

Result:



count(item)
item
name
area




1
24050C24S
DC-STD-03
DC


2
24050C24S
DC-STD-04
DC


1
24050506S
DC-STD-01
DC


1
2405065ES
DC-STD-01
DC


1
2406025CS
DC-STD-01
DC


2
24050E98S
DC-STD-03
DC


1
24050E9BS
DC-STD-03
DC


1
24100258S
DC-STD-04
DC


1
24040A88S
DC-STD-04
DC


1
24050506S
DC-STD-02
DC



Base on above query and result, by right the item 24050506S should has 2 counts, but mysql miss 1 of it.
It is cause by my query or something not right with mysql ?

You're grouping by item and name (and implicitly by area). Since the name values differ, you get separate rows

Incomplete grouping. Either add area to the grouping expression or use 'DC' AS area (according to your WHERE) in the output list. And enable ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY.

I'd suggest removing area from the results. It's redundant due to the static WHERE clause anyway

Item 24050C24S also with diff name but it counted. If I not group item and name, it throw error 1055, exp#3

"Item 24050C24S also with diff name but it counted"... al that means is there are two rows with DC-STD-04 and one with DC-STD-03

This is one of those MySQL peculiarities. In other DBMSs, you always get an error message rather than potentially useless results. For instance, in PostgreSQL: "column "jmr.area" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function". See MySQL Handling of GROUP BY.

Show th original data you are running this query on. But if you think the two rows in your results with 24050506S should be grouped together, you are wrong. Because you are grouping over item and name and those two rows have a different value for name

There are not inputs of table information...
According to query I tried to fix it.
You want to count items, group by item & name where starttime is '2024-05-03' and area is 'DC'.
So, the query is:
SELECT
  count(item) over(partition by item) as count,
  item,
  name,
  area
FROM jmr
WHERE starttime LIKE '2024-05-03%' and area='DC'
group by item, name
order by item, name;

Output: db<>fiddle

What is this answer supposed to tell us ?

@ArtBindu Don't tell people they should upvote answers, that's their own decision.

I don't understand why people giving negative voting

click the up arrow it never show +ve only -1 or -2, no 1, 2, no idea
